# Extracting JSON data with Retrofit and Gson

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, gson, retrofit

I'm trying to figure out how to extract data from my JSON response and loop through the data. I have the following Retrofit code to request the JSON data from my REST API:

```
    final RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(URL)
            .build();

    final ApiEndpointInterface apiService = restAdapter.create(ApiEndpointInterface.class);

    apiService.getJsonData(1, new Callback<User>() {

        @Override
        public void success(User user, Response response) {
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(User.class, new Deserializer()).create();
            User c = gson.fromJson(response.getBody().toString(), User.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
            retrofitError.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

And my deserializer:

```
class Deserializer implements JsonDeserializer<User> {
    @Override
    public User deserialize(JsonElement je, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jdc)
            throws JsonParseException {
        // Get the "content" element from the parsed JSON
        JsonElement content = je.getAsJsonObject().get("data");

        // Deserialize it. You use a new instance of Gson to avoid infinite recursion
        // to this deserializer
        return new Gson().fromJson(content, User.class);

    }
}
```

The JSON response:

```
{
    "success":true,
    "data":[
        {
            "id":"1",
            "username":"User1"
        },
        {
            "id":"2",
            "username":"User2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Within Retrofit's `success` callback, I'm not sure how to actually loop through the data's items and extract the data from it (like the person's username).

Comment: a/ data is not a json object. b/ you don't need to call gson your self, as you can see that your callback already gives you a User object. (but for that to work you'd need to give the gson object to the retrofit builder)

Answer (score 2):

Create this model classes:

```
private class ResponseData {
   public boolean success;
   public List<User> data;
}

private class User {
   public String id;
   public String username;
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
final RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint(URL)
        .build();

final ApiEndpointInterface apiService = restAdapter.create(ApiEndpointInterface.class);

apiService.getJsonData(1, new Callback<ResponseData>() {

    @Override
    public void success(ResponseData responseData, Response response) {
        for (User u : responseData.data) {
           String name = u.username;
           // etc
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
        retrofitError.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

Comment: Error `data is not public in com.project.app.API.ResponseData. Cannot be accessed from outside package`. I tried making it `public List<User> data;`, but I get error `Wrong 2nd argument type. Found retrofit.Callback<com.project.app.API.ResponseData>, required: retrofit.Callback<com.project.app.models.User>`.

Comment: I fixed the snippet. Could you check this again?